# get just 1 command from MSYS2 (GNU for Windows)

Tags: windows

I am looking for the most light weight solution for running linux `test` command on windows. I haven't found a standalone `test.exe` binaries, so I used [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/). It works fine, but I am really after just one command. I tried deleting a bunch of files, but I soon broke the functionality.

How can I get just 1 command, namely `test`?

---

My use case is to determine if file (and just file, no folders here) exists

```
test -f filePath && echo file exists || echo file not found
```

---

I tried using  `exist` command

```
if exist log.txst (echo yes) else (echo no)
```

but it performs incorrectly, because it returns true also for folders

```
if exist . (echo yes) else (echo no) // this should be no, because . is not a file
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/8446): What do you want to use the `test` command for?

Comment: Yeah I guess it is. I've got a script implemented on OSX machine. I need to port it to windows. It relies heavily on bash `test` command. Easiest way to do it so just include test binaries on windows machines too. For example, using `curl` on windows machines was really easy

Comment: Get the `busybox.exe` from [GNU MCU Eclipse Windows Build Tools](https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/windows-build-tools/releases) and rename it to `test.exe`.